# Exception from a prefect task cannot be caught by sys.excepthook

Tags: python, prefect

I have set an exception handler to the `sys.excepthook`:

````py
    def handle_exception(exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback):
        if issubclass(exc_type, KeyboardInterrupt):
            logger.error("KeyboardInterrupt\n")
            sys.__excepthook__(exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback)
            return

        # Preserve the exception info in the log.
        print("UNEXPECTED ERROR OCCURRED!")
        logger.error(
            "Uncaught exception", exc_info=(exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback)
        )

        # Send the exception info to Slack.
        exc_text = (
            f"[Error] *{logger_name}* <@U01HX7R5VPW>\n```"
            + "".join(format_exception(exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback))
            + "```"
        )
        notify(exc_text, critical=True)
    sys.excepthook = handle_exception
````

I am having a prefect flow run as below:

```py
with Flow("stocktwits-crawler", schedule=schedule) as f:
        print("Running...")
        if ...:
                a(...)
        else:
                b(...)
        logger.info("All finished.")
```

The methods `a()` and `b()` have been added with the `@task` decorator.

My problems is: If an error is raised outside of the `a()` and `b()`, my exception handler can catch the message and write into the log files. But when the error is raised inside of the prefect tasks (`a()` and `b()`), the log files output nothing which means the exception handler does not catch the error message. I am not sure if the `prefect task` has another hook for the exception handler. Could you please give me some suggestions about how to further debug this problem?

Answer (score 3):

In general, Prefect manages the state of your flows and tasks, therefore you shouldn't have to build your own exception handlers. Did you know that Prefect has [state handlers](https://docs.prefect.io/core/concepts/notifications.html#notifications-and-state-handlers) that provide this functionality out of the box? [Here](https://gist.github.com/anna-geller/2014180ee5eaec9ea54f4d3f5b98ca93) is an example that sends a full exception traceback via a Slack message.

Additionally, in Prefect <= 1.0 you can't use if/else statements directly in your flow, the same with print and log statements. The Flow constructor can only call tasks and set dependencies. This means that you would have to move this logic to separate functions that you can decorate with `@task`. You can replace the if/else statements with [conditional tasks](https://docs.prefect.io/core/examples/conditional.html#conditional-tasks) such as `case`.